# Is there a way to get tightvnc to host the native display :0?

Tags: vnc, x-windows, tightvnc

tightvncserver starts up just fine using :1, :2, etc, None of the control the default X Server on the monitor itself.

If I change it to :0 I get this error
A VNC server is already running as :0

If I change it back everything works just fine.

Does tightvncserver not run the native display?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible with tightvnserver. Most vncservers will try to build a whole WM (=window manager), while your :0 display has, apparently, all of this.

You can check this by not starting your X server at boot, and before issuing the usual *startx* command, to start tightvncserver on :0. It will work then.

On the other hand, if you are keen on using display :0, you can try x11vnc, which is what I do.

Answer (score 5):

Try x0vncserver.
i.e. On arch:

x0vncserver -display :0 -passwordfile ~/.vnc/passwd

http://tigervnc.org/doc/x0vncserver.html

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC

Comment: And that's in `tigervnc-scraping-server` package on Debian

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
$ sudo apt install tigervnc-scraping-server
```

Setup password

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.vnc
$ vncpasswd
Password:
Verify:
Would you like to enter a view-only password (y/n)? n
```

Starting the VNC server

```
$ x0vncserver -passwordfile ~/.vnc/passwd -display :0
or
$ x0vncserver -localhost no -passwordfile ~/.vnc/passwd -display :0
```

[source](https://gilgil.gitlab.io/2020/05/29/1.html)